# Какие есть способы вести лог всех ошибок приложения в ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Какие есть способы вести лог всех ошибок приложения в ASP.NET Core? Например хотелось бы сохранять все исключения со стеком вызова в текстовые файлы или типа того (автоматические, не в обработчике исключений). Если были получены некорректные данные в контроллере хотелось бы добавить информацию о некорректном запросе в лог.

В идеале хотелось бы иметь инструмент, который, например, присылал бы SMS с сообщением о том, что база данных не отвечает, интернет отвалился, пользователи присылают на конкретный метод конкретного контроллера не те данные и тд.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Добавьте в `Startup` `Middleware`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
}
```

В `Middleware` вы задаёте собственную обработку запросов перед выполнением и после выполнения, так же обработку ошибок.

Реализация `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` (не забудьте зарегистрировать ILogger в контейнере):

```
public sealed class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            _logger.LogError(context, exp);
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, exp.GetBaseException());
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exp)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Code = code, Message = exp.Message, StackTrace = exp.StackTrace });

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

[Документация с Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 5):

Из стандартных: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

В Startup.Configure:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddFile("C:\\log\\Лог.log");
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

Далее через DI их получаем, включая в конструктор ILogger.

Далее в нужных местах пишем Log, обработку. В некоторых местах (где не обработали) может выдать сам ошибку в файл `loggerFactory.AddDebug();`

Возможно если покапаться, то можно писать в поток, а поток отправлять на сервер, который бы вам отправлял нужные вам сообщения.

P.S. Вопрос выше даже без отдельного сервера работает и кажется предоставляет больше данных. Объедините наши ответы и (думаю) получите то, что хотите.
Ну и стоит немного скурить мануалов по `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`